# Route doesn't work for half paths - laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, routes

I'm been having a problem with **Laravel**. My problem is that i have routes connecting to different web pages but half of the web pages doesn't load and the other have them do. I have PHP pages for each of the pages and have them connected.
I get the 404
Here is my routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/index', 'PagesController@index');
Route::get('/hub','PagesController@hub');
Route::get('/basicmod','PagesController@basicmod');
Route::get('/addquestion','PagesController@questions');
Route::get('/addquestion','PagesController@addquestion');
Route::get('/introtest','TestController@index');
```

All the routes connect to a function in the page controller or test controller like :

```
public function addquestion(){
    $title = "Add Question";
    return view('pages.addquestion')->with('title',$title);
}
```

Here is the places where i call the functions :

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://localhost/microskills/public/hun/'"></button>
<button><a href="http://localhost/microskills/public/questions">Questions</a></button>
```

it isn't the function that is not working or the buttons when i type `localhost/skills/public/questions` in the browser it still doesn't work

Comment: You are double-defining routes: `Route::get('/addquestion','PagesController@questions');
Route::get('/addquestion','PagesController@addquestion');` Is this on purpose? You are allowed to have the same signature, just make sure one is post and the other get ;)

Comment: i took the questions Route out and its still not working? i want them both as get

Comment: Well you may want them both as get, but that's just not gonna work. One get, one post OR change the signature.

Answer (score -1):

which routes work, which don't?

if you are running apache, have you activated mod_rewrite?

run this command to activate mod_rewrite in apache:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and then restart apache:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: I have already done that and it is still not working. is there anything else i need to install?